# How to cut non-alphanumeric prefix and suffix from a string in Python?

Tags: python, regex, string, prefix, suffix

How to cut all characters from the beginning and the end of the string which are not alphanumerical?

For example:

```
print(clearText('%!_./123apple_42.juice_(./$)'))
# => '123apple_42.juice'

print(clearText('  %!_also remove.white_spaces(./$)   '))
# => 'also remove.white_spaces'
```

Comment: Where is your attempt to code this?

Comment: `def removePrefix(text, prefix):
    if text.startswith(prefix):
        return text[len(prefix):]
    return text`

I have managed to remove any certain prefix so far, but this is not a general solution. I'm still trying to work out some regex solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This guy grabs everything between alphanumeric characters.

```
import re

def clearText(s):
    return re.search("[a-zA-Z0-9].*[a-zA-Z0-9]", s).group(0)

print(clearText("%!_./123apple_42.juice_(./$)"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Why is the .group(0) field needed? Is there something more added to the search?

Comment: deleted, yea i was going by my skim of the docs but clearly did not read well, appreciate the correction.

Comment: deleted as well then :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use this pattern: `^[^a-zA-Z0-9]+|[^a-zA-Z0-9]+$`

Explanation:

`^[^a-zA-Z0-9]` - match one or more non-alphanumerical character at the beginning of a string (thanks to `^`)

`[^a-zA-Z0-9]$` - match one or more non-alphanumerical character at the end of a string (thanks to `$`)

`|` means alternation, so it matches non alphanumerical string of characters at the begginning or at the end

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/favWlU/1)

Then it's enough to replace matches with empty string.

Comment: I see! Thank you very much, I see the logic is almost the same as @ilamaaa's. I only accepted that so later on the whole solution can be seen, but like given!